# Term for "open" number of hours for an assigned person/resource on an IT contract?

Tags: contracts

Quick question...my wife is drafting a small agreement for her the IT company she works for to work with another IT company in which her company will lend or assign programmers, without limiting or specifying the length of time that the resource will be assigned.

The two companies have worked before and the agreement had a data table for the cost per hour of the resource, depending on his level, and the limit number of hours that could be charged.

In this case, since they will assign the resource, they need to replace the number with a word or a very short phrase that will describe that the number of hours is the total number of hours that the resource worked assigned to them.

I'm not sure what a good word would be...could it be "Open"? Or "Unlimited"? Or "Number of hours worked"? I'm not sure and I tried searching online but couldn't find a good match for what I need.

ANy help is greatly appreciated, since she needs to hand in the draft tomorrow. Thanks!!

Comment: I'd say 'as needed' or 'as required'.

Comment: Isn't that referred to as an "unspecified" number of hours?

Comment: Hey guys. I told my wife all options that you gave and she went for "As Required", says it sounded more formal to her, and although Unspecified matches the scenario too, she didn't like how it looked on the agreement.

Couldn't mark your answer as preferred since you put it as a comment ceejayoz.

But, really thank you all for the very quick answers and taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ongoing", "as needed", "per hour while assigned"?

Answer (score 0):

" .. the number of hours is the **total number of hours** that the resource worked assigned to them."

How about "accumulated" time?